# Apply verbose_name (or similar property) to Wagtail form field tied to a ParentalKey

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

Does anyone know how I might go about updating the string "Landing page group" in the field on the left to "Translation group"?

I'm working on a Wagtail admin page for a Page model. We allow our marketing team to translate pages, and associate them  together, using a "landing page group". Internally we need to maintain that name "Landing page group", but our user testing has indicated that users might be more likely to understand what it's for if we simplify the name to "Translation group".

I've already implented a change to the field which allows users to add a new group name. Adding a meta class with `verbose_name` was easy. However I'm not having quite as simple of a time renaming the primary selection field. I'm including screenshot of the admin panel in question, and some code below that might offer some insight.

We're using Django 2.0.8 and Wagtail 2.5.1.

[image: Locale ad hreflang group]

```py
class LandingPageGroup(ClusterableModel):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    name = models.CharField('Landing Page Group name', max_length=255)

    api_fields = [
        APIField('name'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class LandingPageBaseForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    new_landing_page_group = forms.CharField(required=False, label='New translation group')

class LandingPageBase(Page):
    base_form_class = LandingPageBaseForm
    landing_page_group = ParentalKey(
        'home.LandingPageGroup',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            heading='Locale and Hreflang Group',
            [
                FieldRowPanel(
                    [
                        FieldPanel('landing_page_group', widget=forms.Select),
                        FieldPanel('new_landing_page_group'),
                    ],
                    help_text='Choose an existing landing page group OR create a new one'
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can apply a `verbose_name` property to the ParentalKey.

```
landing_page_group = ParentalKey(
    'home.LandingPageGroup',
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name='Translation group', # <---
)
```

I could swear that tried this, but it works as intended.